# Not able to run PMD in eclipse luna

Tags: eclipse, pmd

i have installed (PMD) 4.0.6 and i am using eclipse Luna and my java version is 1.8._40.Now it is installed ,its opening in editor.

Problem is when i try to check any violation of any file or any project,it won't run and it won't show the violation in editor.

Please tell me how to fix this?